# how to take bigger urls by using URI.parse or Domainatrix.parse but not using gsub or split?

Tags: ruby

```
2.5.0 :150 > url = 'https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/apply'
 => "https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/apply" 
2.5.0 :151 > Domainatrix.parse(url)
 => #<Domainatrix::Url:0x00007fd7850df4a8 @scheme="https", @host="www.online.citibank.co.in", @port="", @url="https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/apply", @public_suffix="co.in", @domain="citibank", @subdomain="www.online", @path="/credit-card/apply", @localhost=false, @ip=false> 
2.5.0 :152 > Domainatrix.parse(url).domain_with_public_suffix
 => "citibank.co.in"
```

its getting "citibank.co.in"

but i required `online.citibank.co.in` with out using gsub or split thing

can any one help

Comment: There is no built in method that gives you what you want straight out the gate since `www` is actually a subdomain and not a seperate part of the URL. You ignore it at your own peril as the server may not redirect from the same URL without `www`.

Comment: its not a part of redirection, i need to bring out online.citibank.co.in from https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/apply & store in DB using Domainatrix

Comment: You're missing the point - its not to redirect but that `www.online.citibank.co.in` and  `online.citibank.co.in` are totally different hosts. It's therefore completely unrealistic to expect that the libraries would know exactly what subdomains you're interested in so you'll have to use a regular expression or split the host name.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`URI#parse`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/URI/parse/class)

While you will get `www` as well it's better to use this as you won't have to handle various cases manually.

```rb
url = 'https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/apply'
#=> "https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/apply"

parsed_url = URI.parse(url)
#=> #<URI::HTTPS https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/apply>

parsed_url.host
#=> "www.online.citibank.co.in"
```

Comment: i already did this but i am trying without gsubs splits etc..

Comment: AFAIK standard libraries will help you get a domain, host etc. but if there is some custom logic I think you will have to build around it